# Python integer division gives wrong result

Tags: python, math

I'm not sure if this is a bug or if I'm just misunderstanding how integer division is supposed to work.

Consider the following code:

```
import math
a = 18000
b = 5500
c = (a-b)/9  # c = 1388.(8)

d = (a-b)/c
e = (a-b)//c
f = math.floor(d)
print(f"(a-b)/c={d}, (a-b)//c={e}, floor={f}")  # outputs (a-b)/c=9.0, (a-b)//c=8.0, floor=9
```

Why is `e` different from `d`? As far as I understand, `num1//num2` should be equal to `math.floor(num1/num2)`.

Using Python 3.8.10 32bit on Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: There's non-integer operations at work here. You have floating point numbers, like `c`. Check whether those are exact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference here is the use of intermediate calculations.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) for more details on floating point representation.

`(a-b)/9` is not exactly representable in floating point. In python it is stored as `1388.888888888888914152630604803562164306640625`

```py
from decimal import Decimal
print(Decimal(c))  # 1388.888888888888914152630604803562164306640625
```

Observe that `c` is actually a little larger than the true value of `(a-b)/9`. Because of this, the true value of `(a-b)/c` is slightly less than `9`. Floor-divide in python gives the floor of the true value of the division, therefore `(a-b)//c` correctly evaluates to `8`.

On the other hand, `(a-b)/c` results in another floating point precision error. Though the true value is slightly less than `9`, the closest value that can be represented is exactly `9`. Applying the floor operation to exactly `9` results in `9`, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Because `c` is a non-integer number of `float` type, the integer-division `//` can lead to unintuitive results. Best to only use `//` when dividing 2 integers with the purpose of creating an `int` as output type.